# Asterisk registration programmatically

Tags: ios, asterisk

I am trying to implement Asterisk server for VOIP in an iPhone application.

I am able to register the user through manually, but I wanted to do the same thing programmatically. I am not sure but there might be some idea like sending through an HTTP request.

If you have any idea or pointer please share with me.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. You want to run a SIP server _on your iPhone_? (And why? And how will you discover it's IP address?) You succeeded to do so but can register only "manually"? What does "manually" means? And from where did you register? From another process on the same iPhone? From an other iPhone? From a VoIP phone? Add some more clarifications to your question because in its current form we can't help you.

Comment: Actually my idea is that if any user is registered on Asterisk server then through that user id we can comunicate to one another.

Comment: Manually means i am able to register user throgh going on Asterisk server web page then in register colum we can add any numberof users.but if we are on cell it's burden to go again and again and then fill particulars .did you get some idea?

Comment: @Costiqe:did you  get some idea what's i am trying to explain you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is hard because is necessary modify the dial plan in order to add a sip account. but you can program a web service that read a text file with the extensions from your mobile.

Answer (score 3):

I think the thing that you are looking for is called *SIP client*. You install the client on the iPhone and it will register to your SIP server (let it be Asterix or anything else). Then you can make VoIP calls between the clients registered contemporary, send instant messages, exchange files or even implement some custom protocol over SIP to exchange other type of data.

There are a lot of SIP client applications for iPhone, and even a couple of *SIP stacks* that is a framework that allows you to build your own SIP client application through its API calls, so you will have full control on everything. One of the most mature of these with iPhone support is [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/). Check out their web site to see whether this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have no idea why the other answer was accepted. Based on the limited information, this appears to be a more correct answer.

Comment: Nevertheless I work with VoIP for years already, honestly speaking I don't understand a word from the other answer :)

Answer (score -1):

it is nto fully clear from your desription what exactly you want, but probably this one will help

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out